# Kivy cannot find PIL module in Mac

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

OSX 10.10.2, Python 2.7.9, Kivy 1.9

I used `sudo pip install Pillow` to install Pillow when i get the not found error. I can find PIL in `python help('modules')` but not in `kivy help('modules')`

I tried Kivy user group but got no reply yet. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kivy 1.9 package uses it's own Virtual Environment. You have to make sure to install modules into that. Simply do::

```
kivy -m pip install pillow
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this answer. Have been scouring Stackoverflow for a Mac specific answer.

Comment: Be careful for me the version 3.0.0 of pillow wasn't compatible with kivy (it works with the 2.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

Probably kivy is looking for the Pillow package in the wrong place.
You should check where your library is installed and use that path.
The path should be something like "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/", look if you have the PIL package in that position.

Then set the PYTHONPATH variable or use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_the_PILLOW_package')
```

and look if "import PIL" raises an ImportError.