# Importing libraries in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to import the "requests" library into my Kivy application. How do I go about that? Simply giving import requests is not working out.

Edit:
I'm using Kivy on Mac OS X, 10.10.3.

Comment: Apparently you don't have requests installed in your kivy python environment. Install it.

Comment: Yes. How do I go about it?

Comment: `pip install requests` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

Comment: No I've already installed requests on my Python environment. When I import requests to a simple Python program it works, but when I import it into my kivy application, it doesn't work.

Comment: So you haven't installed requests in *kivy's* python environment. I guess you are using windows (it's best if you note this in the question)?

Comment: No I haven't installed requests in kivy's environment. I'm using a Mac. Sure I'll add it to the question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a Mac specific answer, I tried
`kivy -m pip install requests`.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615546/kivy-cannot-find-pil-module-in-mac) helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows with kivy's portable package, I think you can get a shell with kivy's env by running the kivy executable. Assuming so, I think you can run `pip install requests` in this shell to install it to kivy's environment.

Edit: I see you've now noted you are using OS X, but something similar may be true. I don't know about this though.